# Radeon 270X Temp Sensors Show Nothing When No Monitors Plugged In (Headless)

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, temperature, amd-radeon

I have two radeon 270X video cards. When checking the GPU temperature via GPU-Z, the temperature sensors work fine as long as I have a monitor plugged in.

Once I unplug the monitor, the sensors show no data and there are no more readings.

Is there a way to make sure they stay active even when no monitor is plugged in?

I'm concerned, since I am using the GPUs (without any monitors attached), and I don't want them to overheat.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue was with RDP (remote desktop) since it doesn't actually use the videocard at all.

Solution: use VNC

Comment: Did you ever find a non VNC solution for getting the sensors to register without a monitor plugged in?  Does using VNC cause both cards to register the temperature?

Comment: I've had no reason to look beyond the VNC solution since it works. All my card's sensors work while VNC is active.